# Hudson CI - Workspace view sortable?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

a short question on Hudson CI:

Is it possible to sort the output of a job's workspace view?

What I mean is this:

We have a test suite running as a Hudson job.
Each run creates a new folder in the workspace where all the results are stored.
The problem is that those folders are labeled using the date and thus the newest one is put to the end of the list, like this:

2011_02_28-12_00
2011_02_28-13_00
2011_02_28-14_00

etc.

Now, if I have a number of these folders, i need to scroll down in order to get the newest entry.

Is there a way to reverse the sorting in the workspace view?

I did neither find any suitable information on google nor a plugin that provides this.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible by default.

Why do not you make your own plugin (?)

Comment: Well, I might write a plugin for that. However, that issue is not that annoying to be allowed to invest that much time into a solution. My first intention was to check wether there are built in facilities or existing plugins that I could use and didn't find.

Comment: Javascript manipulation? That would be a one-time solution, wouldn't it? If I'd need to always manipulate JS/DOM in Firebug, I could also scroll everytime instead.